# Harvesting the Power of Visual SVG with PHP/PYTHON/other programming language

Tags: php, python, svg

Me and my friend want to build something with `SVG and PHP or PYTHON`.

Is there any integration/ workflows that connect programming languages together with powerfull visual interfaces, such as SVG? Are there other promising visual ways than `SVG`?

Comment: My favorite SVG project is SVGedit, but it is javascript based. [Check it out](http://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are a couple of ways you can manipulate SVG dynamically with the Python language.

First, you could use the Apache Batik library, which provides a first-class implementation of SVG built on Java technologies. You can use any JVM language to develop against the Batik API. Furthermore, you can use Jython for scripting: http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/extending.html#interpreters

Second, you could use PyGTK Webkit bindings to manipulate SVG content using Webkit's implementation of SVG. See here for how to get set up with Webkit and PyGTK: http://www.tuxradar.com/content/python-pygtk-webkit-20-minutes

Both of these approaches would be at the level of manipulating the SVG DOM, and thus can be used to add dynamic behaviour. However, if you just want to generate static content, then indeed, any language that can generate XML would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Try [pySVG](http://codeboje.de/pysvg/). SVG 'format' is essentially XML so you could use any xml library if you write all the tags yourself.